# I lost a file on Pentaho, how do I get it back?

Tags: database, bigdata, pentaho

I am trying to get back a transformation from a repository where it disappeared.

I was working on a transformation and then I lost connection. When I reconnected the transformation that already existed and I was just modifying disappeared.

Pentaho tells me that the file does not exist anymore

Comment: I think all is lost now, however you should specify which software of the Pentaho suite you are using and its version, so we can see if by chance it has some automatic backup function

Comment: I am using pentaho 8.2. The thing is how is it possible that the transformation disappeared if it already existed?

Comment: I was modifying queries in some objects

Comment: "Pentaho" ia a *group* of products. Are you talking about "Pentaho Data Integration" or "Pentaho Business Analytics"?

Comment: Pentaho Data Integration

Comment: Did you close the program anymoment during this experience?

Comment: No I did not..I just think the transformation cancelled in a loop. It is fine tho...I'll try to get it back from a backup